# cutting titles/features/subvideos out of a VOB file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, dvd, vob

I have a VOB video file obtained from a DVD. The video contains several separate subvideos from the DVD, which play one-after-another (e.g., the first subvideo is the main feature, the second subvideo is a bonus feature, the third subvideo is another bonus feature, etc.). So when I play the VOB file using a program such as VLC, the time display starts at 00:00, and then resets to 00:00 several times throughout the video when each of the subvideos begins. Also note that I'm not sure if the correct term for "subvideo" is "title", "feature", or something else.

Since the start times of each subvideo are somehow embedded in the VOB file, is there a way to use ffmpeg to automatically cut these subvideos out of the video into separate VOB files? I'm trying to avoid having to cut them out manually by specifying their start and end timepoints via the `-ss` and `-to` options, which is tedious.

Comment: A more sophisticated tool like Handbrake can easily do it with the added bonus of having a GUI.

Comment: The data for the titles and chapters is in the IFO file and not the VOBs. Without the IFO you're stuck with just the timestamps on each frame (the details of which I am fuzzy on). Off the top of my head I know of no easy way to trim at each point the TS resets to 0. It would likely be quite the scripting challenge to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

A fork of ffmpeg can help :
[vgtMPEG](http://godromo.com/gmt/vgtmpeg) which is based on FFmpeg and makes it easy to extract individual titles, chapters and language tags from DVD and BD.
To show tracks, chapters and titles :

```
vgtmpeg.exe -i dvd://d:\
```

and to extract for example data from title #10 :

```
vgtmpeg.exe -i dvd://d:\?title=10 -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:s -c copy -f dvd title10.mpg -f ffmetadata title10.chap
```

Comment: Do you know if this program can be applied directly to VOB files? I had known that you can extract titles directly from DVDs using `mplayer`, for example.

Comment: @Trevor It seems need DVD/BD media or at least an image (iso ...)

Comment: Ok thanks for the info

Comment: According to the linked page: "‘path_to_dvd’ can also be any of the individual files inside the VIDEO_TS folder, ‘vgtmpeg’ will figure out the rest."  I'm guessing it needs a complete VIDEO_TS folder (or IFO+VOB at a minimum, if it chooses to be nice).  Just the VOBs likely will not work.